# Why do we need 3 equations to determine the position of a point in 2D space?

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

Given the following problem: [Finding location of a point on 2D plane, given the distances to three other know points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/finding-location-of-a-point-on-2d-plane-given-the-distances-to-three-other-know?newreg=48e2a00c2b8f46c9b60265f1f33a37e5),

we can find the position of the point using 3 other known points, which gives us three equations. My question is, why are 2 points/ 2 equations not enough for these kinds of problems? Two unknowns ($x_0$, $y_0$) should only require two equations, right?

More precisely, given $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, $y_2$, $d_1$ and $d_2$, why can't we solve for $x_0$ and $y_0$ (exactly) using the following formulas:

$$(x_0-x_1)^2+(y_0-y_1)^2=d_1^2$$
$$(x_0-x_2)^2+(y_0-y_2)^2=d_2^2 $$

I understand that the squares introduce $\pm$, but I've never needed more than 2 equations to solve for 2 unknowns before and it's rubbing me the wrong way.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: each equation represents a circle. Two circles can intersect at 0,1 or 2 points.

Comment: @DatBoi or every point

Comment: @DavidRaveh ah yes of course! I believe the given points would be distinct, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @DatBoi The intuition for it does make sense, but having never needed 3 equations for 2 unknowns, I am still quite uncomfortable with this. Does this only happen when the variables we are solving for are squared? Or can this happen in other circumstances? 

Thank you!|

Comment: @Bouch You can absolutely solve for the unknowns using just two equations. Solving this may yield, for say, 2 sets of solutions, like i mentioned above. However, notice that we're trying to determine a unique point in the plane. Adding another equation **possibly** gets rid of the other solution, yielding you a unique solution, ie, a unique point in the plane.

Comment: @DatBoi Hmmm, sounds fair. I guess each equation reduces the size of the solution space by 1, and 2 solutions are not equivalent to a whole degree of freedom. Thank you!